# Detect Slow Network Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, networking

I need to intercept the slow network event in my Angular 9 app.

Any way to do this?

I already detecting offline and online event, but I need the slow network event detection

here is my code to online and offline event detection

```
this.onlineEvent = fromEvent(window, 'online');
this.offlineEvent = fromEvent(window, 'offline');
this.slowLineEvent = fromEvent(window, 'slowline');
this.subscriptions.push(this.onlineEvent.subscribe(e => {
  this.connectionStatusMessage = 'Back to online';
  this.connectionStatus = 'online';
  this.error = { type: 'ok', color: 'rgb(80, 218, 0)', message: 'CONNECTION.OK' };
}));

this.subscriptions.push(this.offlineEvent.subscribe(e => {
  this.connectionStatusMessage = 'Connection lost! You are not connected to internet';
  this.connectionStatus = 'offline';
  this.error = { type: 'offline', color: 'red', message: 'CONNECTION.OFFLINE' };
}));
```